# Optimal way to delete dependencies

Tags: node.js, macos, gruntjs, dependencies

I've installed some front-end stuff with Bower.io which came with dependencies for GruntJS. I've installed those with npm install.

There is a node_modules folder in there now. The NPM docs only show how to remove packages one at a time.

Can't I just delete the node_modules folder in the finder when I am done?
Do I NEED to use the terminal to remove all the packages one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can just remove the node-modules folder. A fresh `npm install` will rebuild it.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't added installed modules into package.json, you can remove all these modules with command:

```
npm prune
```

If you have added the module into package.json in `dependencies` section, then you should use the command:

```
npm un -S <module_name>
```

And if the module is added in `devDependencies` section, use the command:

```
npm un -D <module_name>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info:)